# Better method to get users belonging to no role?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-membership, user-roles

I wrote the following that does work, but want to know if there is any more efficient ways to get all users without any role.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Security;

public static IEnumerable<MembershipUser> GetUsersHavingNoRole() {
  var allUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>();
  foreach (var user in allUsers) {
    if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName).Length.Equals(0)) {
      yield return user;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect there to usually be more users than roles - so it *might* make sense to iterate over the roles (return by `Roles.GetAllRoles()`), build up a list of users in any of those roles (e.g. by creating a `HashSet<string>` and adding the users for each role returned by `Roles.GetUsersInRole`), and then finding the difference between that and all the users. So if you're using LINQ, you could use:

```
var usersInRolesQuery = Roles.GetAllRoles()
                             .SelectMany(role => Roles.GetUsersInRole(role));

var usersInRoles = new HashSet<string>(usersInRolesQuery);
return Membership.GetAllUsers()
                 .Cast<MembershipUser>()
                 .Where(user => !usersInRoles.Contains(user.UserName));
```

Of course that's still dealing with the same amount of data - but it *may* mean fewer roundtrips to whatever datastore is involved.

Have you benchmarked the application to find out how expensive your current method is?

Comment: Usually more users than roles, you mean? ;)

Comment: This is nice; I've learned from it. I haven't benchmarked--my user-base is so small it wouldn't make any difference, but I like to learn the better techniques. Maybe for a larger application, the method could compare the number of users to roles up-front before using either method, but like you said, users are almost always going to outnumber roles unless you have a LOT of unused roles.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of users, roles and relations in between them and the number of times you need this information, it **might** be worth it (had enough disclaimers yet?) to add an extra method to the (custom)Role Provider.

The native query that is required in the provider **could** be much more efficient than using LINQ the way you are doing now.

A lot depends on the factors in first line of this answer but also on the provider. Maintainability might also be an issue as you are adding a query that might not be supported in the future (next version of the provider)

Comment: Thanks for this. I suppose the number of users would be well into the thousands (or hundreds of thousands?) to get too concerned. In that case, I guess it'd be easier to automatically assign a default role to all new users and eliminate the need to worry about this category of user.

Comment: :) That is what I do. Although it would have been nice if the API allowed us to query for the users without roles.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly. This code should help!

```
MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
MembershipUserCollection usersNoRoles = new MembershipUserCollection();

    foreach (MembershipUser user in users)
    {
        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName);

        // if roles empty
        if (roles.Count() == 0)
        {
            // Add User to a List for User with no Roles
            usersNoRoles.Add(user);
        }

   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I fail to see how this an improvement over the starting code.